# Edit Distance variation

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, dynamic-programming

Going through "Introduction to algorithms" by "Cormen et al ", I came across a very popular question of dynamic programming named as "Edit Distance". While reading it and devising its solution I got troubled with a possible variation of the same. 
 
Suppose the question is as:
We are given two strings and operations: copy, insert, delete, match, twiddle, kill.
Also as input we are given the number of transformations (say: **n**).
Find if it is possible to transform first string to second in exactly "n" transformations .
**Note:** The number of transformations given may be greater than the minimum number of transformations.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What are "twiddle" and "kill"?

Comment: is this a homework problem? I remember seeing it in the exercise section in CLRS